# Mail not working. Laravel

Tags: php, gmail, laravel-5

I'm trying to use reset password option of laravel. I have used `Route::auth();` in my routes.
I have changed my .env into following:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemailaddress
MAIL_PASSWORD=myapppassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Also in my mail.php file

```
 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => 'myemailaddress', 'name' => 'Myname'],
   'username' => env('myemailaddress'),
'password' => env('myapppassword'),
```

When i click resetpassword from default resetpassword view, it shows following error.

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
#10060]
```

I cant figure out what's wrong in here. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your gmail account to allow "less secure apps" to send emails via your account. This can be done:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps